# Checking the state of data is completely written into the file or not?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a set of data that i am storing into internal storage to be read for the next time. All i need to know if the file is completely written or not. because if not then for the next time read it will give a corrupt file. I need to avoid that.

I need something like a callback or a flag that tells data is completely written or not

Comment: Yes that needs to be avoided. We agree.

Comment: do we a possible solution for this

Comment: Of course. You have to code that in the right way. What are you asking exactly? And let your save function return a boolean which indicates that.

Comment: is there a listener or a flag that is set or triggered once the complete data is saved into the file

Comment: Where do you want to put a listener? Or a flag?

Comment: i have a huge data to be loaded into a file. If the app crashes during the write opertation than complete data wont be written . How can i assure that the data is completely wriiten into the file. Thats why i need a callback or a flag that will be set once the file is correctly written

Comment: I see no file. Where are you talking about? I cannot believe that you still did not post your code. It should have been clear from my first comment. Further you should not let your app crash but catch the exception that lets your app crash. Then you know what went wrong already.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this problem could be checking whether the `File` is empty or not.

So How to Check that would be:

```
val file = File("filepath/file.txt")
if (file.length == 0) {
    // empty or doesn't exist
} else {
    // exists and is not empty
}
```

Comment: but it wont tell if the data present in the file is written completely or not

Comment: You can if you know the exact/approximate amount of bytes that the file should be . You can replace the condition with `length == amountOfBytes`